# DB object not working (PHP): "Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, database, object

I'm doing a little PHP and trying to query a database and then do something with the returned rows object. My page keeps saying: "Call to a member function query() on a non-object"

Here's the PHP:

```
public function __contruct() {
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=DBName;host=mysql.our.host", 'User_Admin_Name', 'Password');
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

public function getEvents() {
    $sql = 'SELECT this FROM that';
    $rows = $this->db->query($sql); //This is the line that the error indicates is problematic
}
```

Does anyone know why it can't recognize db as a regular db object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
public function __contruct() {
                     ^
```

The word `construct` is mispelled (**contruct**) unless that was a typo.

Try it now:

```
public function __construct() {
```

---

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=DBName;host=mysql.our.host", 'User_Admin_Name', 'Password');
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

public function getEvents() {
    $sql = 'SELECT this FROM that';
    $rows = $this->db->query($sql); //This is the line that the error indicates is problematic
}
```

Comment: I myself have made that mistake a few times. I've stared at it for a full minute till it hit me. @CaptainStack